# Having issue with reading Plist into UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am trying to display a dictionary plist into UITableView , I have read many question and answer here but no luck ! it seems cells return null ! here is my plist :
[image]

and my codes :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {


    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"feed" ofType:@"plist"];
    newsFeed = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return newsFeed.count;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return dictionary.allKeys.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   dictionary = [newsFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
   cell.textLabel.text = [[newsFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"title"];

    return cell;

}
```

and the result is nothing :

[image]

Comment: whats the value in dictionary?

Comment: @Rajneesh071 NSDictionary *dictionary;

Comment: i am asking about value, where you are setting value in it

Comment: @Rajneesh071 What you mean ? you can see all its values on the picture

Comment: what output you want????? mean how to display result?

Comment: Your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method doesn't appear to be creating a cell. Where do you create it, or dequeue it from the tableview?  The `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method also doesn't appear to be setting up `dictionary`. Where are you doing that?

Comment: @rickerbh I remove that lines to save space ;)

Comment: have you connected UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate? if not then create them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in you want to display only title then try this

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {

        return newsFeed.count;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        dictionary = [newsFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"title"];

        return cell;

    }
```

**EDIT**
And if you want to display all record then try this

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return newsFeed.count;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return dictionary.allKeys.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    dictionary = [newsFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    NSString *key =[[dictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [dictionary valueForKey:key];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: whats the NSLog of newsFeed?

Comment: Try this  dictionary = [newsFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]; cell.textLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"title"];

Comment: check my answer again for numberOfSectionsInTableView

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Set the Root As `NSDictionary`, put your `newsFeed` in the dictionary.
2. Use `NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary ...fromFile:...];`
3. `newsFeed = [dict valueForKey:@"some_key"];`

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how to debug problems like this. Or if you tried, you should tell us what you tried in the question.

Set a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` and make sure, the plist is loaded correctly. The path might be wrong. The file might be corrupt or have a different root object then what you're expecting.

Set a breakpoint in `numberOfSectionsInTableView`. Is it called at all? Is it called before or after you load your plist? Probably after. In that case you need to call `[tableView reloadData]`. If it's called what do you return.

Continue like this, step for step until you find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,I use plist's a lot.

In ViewDidLoad

```
 NSString *plistPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.plistName];

 self.tableContents=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

 NSLog(@"table %@",self.tableContents);
 NSLog(@"table with Keys %@",[self.tableContents allKeys]);

 self.sortedKeys =  [[self.tableContents allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:[self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section]];
    return [listData count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

    NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:[self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView
                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                 reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",[listData objectAtIndex:row]]; //take your object out

return cell;
}
```